# How do I access Object.keys(object).length from a directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that will list all the errors contained in an errors object (`{phone: ["is required"]`}, but **only if the object is non-empty**.  (It doesn't make sense to say "The following errors…" when there were none.)

I figured out how to check if an object is empty by testing `Object.keys(errors).length`.  **The problem is that I can't figure out how to access Object.keys from my directive template.**  Is this possible?

Since Angular expressions are "evaluated" (using `$parse`, not `eval()` ) in the context of a `scope` instead of in the context of `window`, we don't have access to things like `Object` from the directives template, because `Object` isn't a property of the scope. (Docs: [Expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression))

Makes sense so far.  It goes on to say that "Unlike JavaScript, where names default to global `window` properties, Angular expressions must use `$window` explicitly to refer to the global `window` object. For example, if you want to call `alert()` in an expression you must use `$window.alert()`.

But I can't seem to access `Object` even if I do `$window.Object`.  What am I missing?

---

Here's the code for the directive I'm debugging (and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerRick/hNQq3/2/)):

app.js.coffee:

```js
…
.directive 'displayErrorsAllKeys', ->
  {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      errors: '='
      debug: '@debug'
    }
    templateUrl: 'templates/display-errors-all-keys'
  }

.run(['$rootScope', ($rootScope) ->
  $rootScope.nonEmpty = (object) ->
    !! Object.keys(object).length
])

.controller('TestDisplayErrorsAllKeys',
['$scope',
( $scope ) ->

  $scope.other_errors = {}

  $scope.add_errors = ->
    $scope.other_errors = {"surname":["is required"],"phone":["is required"]}

  $scope.clear_errors = ->
    $scope.other_errors = {}
])
```

display-errors-all-keys.ngt.haml:

```haml
.errors(ng-show="$window.Object.keys(errors).length > 0")
  %p The following errors prevented this from saving:
  %div(ng-repeat="(key, error_messages) in errors") {{key}}: {{error_messages | toSentence}}
```

test_ng_display-errors-all-keys.html.haml

```haml
:scss
  .errors {
    color: red;
  }

%div(ng-app='MyApp')
  %form(ng-controller="TestDisplayErrorsAllKeys")
    %p errors: {{ other_errors }}
    %p nonEmpty(other_errors): {{ nonEmpty(other_errors) }}
    %hr/

    %div(display-errors-all-keys errors="other_errors")

    %input(type="button" value="Add errors" ng-click="add_errors()")/
    %input(type="button" value="Clear errors" ng-click="clear_errors()")/
```

I finally got it to work by defining a helper method in my scope and calling that instead (`$root.nonEmpty(errors)`) (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerRick/hNQq3/2/) for working demo).

This is probably a *pretty* good solution, but:

1. Is there an even better way to solve this?  How would you have done it (written the `ng-show` expression)?
2. How would I get it to work using `Object.keys(errors).length` directly in the `ng-show`??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would provide the helper function in the directives scope (which is isolated). Typically by providing a link function for the directive:

```
.directive('displayErrorsAllKeys', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            errors: '=',
            debug: '@debug'
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.errorsExists = function(object) {
                return object && Object.keys(object).length;
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/display-errors-all-keys'
    };
})
```

Placing logic and data in the root scope is seldom a good practice. Also note that I named the function errorExists, which provides som abstraction upon the actual representation of the errors.

As for your second question, you could add `scope.Object = Object;` in your link function, but *DON'T!* Such specific logic doesn't belong in your template. The template should be concerned with wether or not to show the errors, but not *why*.

Comment: Good answer and good explanation!  Though I still wish there were an easier way to check if an object is non-empty from your template, like (now that I think of it) maybe a filter: `ng-show="errors | nonEmpty"`...

Comment: A filter could be a very good idea, I agree! It reads well and provides some level of abstraction. Seems like a legitimate cause to be able to check existence of errors throughout the app.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a `nonEmpty` filter I added to solve this problem ([JavaScript equivalent](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aapp%0A%0A.filter%20%27nonEmpty%27,%20-%3E%0A%20%20%28object%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20!!%20%28object%20&&%20Object.keys%28object%29.length%20%3E%200%29%0A))

```
.filter 'nonEmpty', ->
  (object) ->
    !! (object && Object.keys(object).length > 0)
```

Tests:

```
%div {{ null | nonEmpty }} should be false
%div {{ { } | nonEmpty }} should be false
%div {{ {a: '1'} | nonEmpty }} should be true
```

My ng-show condition in the example above can be simplified to just this:

```
ng-show="errors | nonEmpty"
```

Now I can easily reuse this check logic, without having to add a new method to each directive or controller where I may want to use it.