# How do I debug/dump a value from an ng-bind {{ }} Angular expression?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a good way to dump or inspect the results of an expression?  Sometimes when I do

```
{{some_expression}}
```

, nothing shows up on the page where the result of that expression should show up.  How do I determine if the expression returned a `null`, an `undefined`, or an empty string `''`?

If  it's a normal object, like this, it will show a nice programmer-friendly representation of the object, which is great:

```
{{ {'a': 1} }}
```

But if you try to inspect an expression that evaluates to null, undefined, or '', they are all **indistinguishable from each other**!

```
{{null}}
{{undefined}}
{{''}}
```

So how can you tell which one it was??

I tried using `JSON.stringify`:

```
{{ JSON.stringify(null) }}
```

but `JSON` seems to be unavailable from an Angular expression because it's a method from `window` and not a property of the scope (see [related question about accessing methods from window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852388/how-do-i-access-object-keysobject-length-from-a-directive-template)).

I tried using `typeof`:

```
typeof {}: {{ typeof {'a': 1} }}
```

but it results in an error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [ typeof {'a': 1} ] starting at [{'a': 1} ].
```

So how can I get it to dump the value into the template using something like `JSON.stringify` (… or `console.log`)?

---

Generally speaking, is there a good way to debug Angular expressions other than trial and error?  Since Angular [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) are so "forgiving", they don't seem to raise errors; they just silently swallow the errors and return `undefined`:

> In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates
>   ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is
>   forgiving to undefined and null.

But without seeing some kind of error message, how do you know what part of the expression Angular had trouble with?

Comment: You can directly access the watchers of a scope and run them. After all `{{ expression }}` compiles to a function you can run. Also, you should have very simple logic in bracketed expressions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add a custom filter for debugging purposes:

```
app.filter('debug', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (input === '') return 'empty string';
    return input ? input : ('' + input);
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
{{ value | debug }}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/U44BCjBhgsFedRkHASlc?p=preview

Comment: alternative: return function(input) { console.log(JSON.stringify(input)); return input; }

Answer (score 13):

The recommended way is to use AngularJS's logging service `$log`. First you need to inject the service into your controller and assign it to a scope variable like so:

```
app.controller('MyCntrl', function($log){
    $scope.$log = $log;
```

Then in your template, us it like ay other function:

```
<span>{{$log.log(value}}</span>
```

If you want to be able to use typeof, it works basically the same way:

```
$scope.getTypeOf = function(val){ return typeof val; };

<span>{{getTypeOf(val)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 7):

The built-in JsonPipe might be easier...

```
{{ object | json }}
```

See: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Answer (score 3):

Based on **tasseKATT**'s and **ogc-nick**'s great answers, I added these two filters.  They're written in CoffeeScript but here's the [JavaScript equivalent](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aapp%0A%0A.filter%20%27debug%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%28input%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20typeof%20input%20is%20%27undefined%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27undefined%27%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20JSON.stringify%28input%29%0A%0A.filter%20%27typeof%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%28input%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20typeof%20input%0A) if you prefer.  Posting here in case it's helpful to anyone else...

```
.filter 'debug', ->
  (input) ->
    if typeof input is 'undefined'
      'undefined'
    else
      JSON.stringify(input)

.filter 'typeof', ->
  (input) ->
    typeof input
```

Now I can get some meaningful debugging output from each of the following expressions:

```
  {{null | debug}}
  {{undefined | debug}}
  {{'' | debug}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, you can try the [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) extension which allows you to inspect properties on your models. Access it by opening the developer console (CTRL+SHIFT+I), and then you should see a Batarang tab. You'll have to click to enable, and then you should get a listing of all Angular models present on your page.  They won't be intuitively named, but you can click through them and deduce which ones are which.

Have you tried putting the `console.log()` inside the double curlies?  That might also work if you just want a quick and lazy method.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey.  Yes, I use the Batarang extension sometimes, but in this case I was wanting something that I could use to debug directly from within my `{{ }}`.  Yes, I've tried `{{ console.log('a') }}`, but nothing shows up in the console when I do that, and nothing shows up as output from the `{{ }}` either (it returned `undefined`).